# ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Tags: python, json

I made a python crawler that takes a json from a particular site.

I tried to form the file so I can extract the data to be able to save to a database.

function for extract script:

```
s = page_ad.findAll('script')[27].text.replace('\'', '"')
s = re.search(r'\{.+\}', s, re.DOTALL).group() # get json data
s = re.sub(r'//.+\n', '', s) # replace comment
s = re.sub(r'\s+', '', s) # strip whitspace
s = re.sub(r',}', '}', s) # get rid of last , in the dict
```

Result after function:

```
{varsource="".toLowerCase();if(mobileSources.indexOf(source)!=-1){returntrue;}returnfalse;}functiongetSource(){varmsiteSources=["mobile","msite"];varuserAgent=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();varsource="".toLowerCase();if(mobileSources.indexOf(source)!=-1){if(msiteSources.indexOf(source)!=-1){source="msite";varresultMatch=userAgent.match(/\olx-source\/(\w+);/);if(resultMatch){source=resultMatch[1];}}}else{source="web";}returnsource;}dataLayer=function(){varinitialDatalayer={"config":{"lurkerURL":"},"site":{"isMobile":isMobile(),"source":getSource()},"page":{"pageType":"ad_detail","detail":{"parent_category_id":"2000","category_id":"2020","state_id":"2","region_id":"31","ad_id":"382568903","list_id":"314710679","city_id":"9238","zipcode":"32606174","price":"19900"},"adDetail":{"adID":"382568903","listID":"314710679","sellerName":"MichelleAlcântara","adDate":"2017-03-1113:10:55","mainCategory":"Veículosebarcos","mainCategoryID":"2000","subCategory":"Carros","subCategoryID":"2020","state":"MG","ddd":"31","region":"BeloHorizonteeregião","price":"19900"}},"session":{"user":{"userID":null,"loginType":null}},"pageType":"Ad_detail","abtestingEnable":"1","listingCategory":"2020","adId":"382568903","state":"2","region":"31","category":"2020","pictures":"5","listId":"314710679","loggedUser":"0","referrer":""};if(self.adParams){for(keyinadParams){varpage=initialDatalayer.page;page.detail[key]=adParams[key];if(page.adDetail){page.adDetail[key]=adParams[key];}}}return[initialDatalayer];}
```

But when I try to convert to json it shows me this error.

Json convert:

```
dataLayer = json.loads(s)
```

Message error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "libs/olx/crawler_ads_information.py", line 100, in <module>
    run(link_base)
  File "libs/olx/crawler_ads_information.py", line 38, in run
    information = getVehicleInformation(page_ad)
  File "libs/olx/crawler_ads_information.py", line 49, in getVehicleInformation
    dataLayer = json.loads(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Comment: What do you see when you just `print s` ?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a serialized data structure, not just plain javascript code.

this is a valid JSON:

```
{"key" : value, "key2" : "value2_string"}
```

which can be "converted" to a python dict.

the string you are trying to `loads` is just a mere javascript code.

you can get more info about JSON here: http://json.org/